# How do you translate this sentence from St. Augustine?

Tags: augustinus

I am stumped on translating this sentence.

> da mihi, domine, scire et intellegere utrum sit prius invocare te an
>   laudare te, et scire te prius sit an invocare te.

A translation from Georgetown translates it like this:

> Grant me, Lord, to know and understand which is first, to call on Thee
>   or to praise Thee? and, again, to know Thee or to call on Thee?

But doesn't *utrum* mean *whether*? I feel like *utrum*...*an* belong together. Do they form the phrase "whether... or..."?

The entire thing puzzles me completely. Could anyone do a play-by-play translation of its parts?

Answer (score 10):

You're basically there. *Utrum ... an* can indeed be taken as "whether ... or":

> *da mihi, domine, scire et intellegere* "grant me, Lord, to know and understand"
>   *utrum sit prius invocare te an laudare te* "whether it is first to call on you or to praise you"
>   *et scire te prius sit an invocare te* "and (whether) it is first to know you or to call on you"

The translation you quote takes a slightly different tack, apparently taking *utrum* as the neuter of *uter* "which of two?" So the second part becomes "which of the two is first, to know you or to understand you". But there's no real difference in meaning between these two options; in fact, this sentence is presumably an example of exactly the type of context in which *utrum* "which of two?" acquired its sense of "whether".